# Euler characteristic of topological pair (Y,X)

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given an inclusion map $i: X\hookrightarrow Y$ between two spaces, I know that the relative chain complex is defined by $$C_k(Y,X)=C_k(Y)/C_k(X)$$ However, I am confused about how the Euler characteristic of the pair is defined and how to find it. Is it the same as finding $\chi(Y/X)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the Euler characteristic of the pair $(X, Y)$ is defined as
$$ \chi(X, Y) = \sum_{i} (-1)^i\text{rank} \ H_i (X, Y),$$
where $H_i(X, Y)$ is the $i$th relative homology group for the pair $(X, Y)$ (i.e. the  homology group obtained from the relative chain complex that you describe in your post).

However, if $(X, Y)$ is a good pair, then $H_i(X, Y)$ is isomorphic to $\widetilde{H}_i (X / Y)$, the $i$th reduced homology group for the quotient space $X / Y$. So we have
$$ \chi(X, Y) = \chi(X / Y) - 1. $$
(The $-1$ accounts for the discrepancy between reduced and unreduced homology in dimension zero.)